# Does this have a name: If an odd prime $p$ does not divide $a$, then $p$ divides $a^n + 1$ or $a^n - 1$

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, divisibility

After seeing and doing a bunch of proofs like "For all $a$ in the natural numbers, then if $7$ does not divide $a$, then $7$ divides $a^3+1$ or $a^3-1$," I conjectured the following, but got stuck in proving it. I'd like to know if it has an actual name, or whether this is just something rather trivial and pointless.

> Given a prime $p$ of the form $2n+1$, for all $a$ in the natural numbers if $p$ does not divide $a$, then $p$ divides $a^n+1$ or $a^n-1$.

*Assume non-trivial $a$

Thanks very much.

Comment: Every odd prime number is of the form $2n+1$, by the way. So it's every prime number except $2$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was trying to make it clear. Stating it as an odd prime means I have to waste a sentence with defining n. But if there's a more elegant way of stating this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well known.  Let $p = 2n + 1$ be an odd prime.  Then, it is known that if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$, then $a^{p-1} = a^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, by [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).  Hence, $(a^n)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ so that $a^n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}$.

You do need to know that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ has exactly two solutions when $p > 2$ is prime, but this is a consequence of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (The [integers mod $p$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integers_modulo_n#Integers_modulo_n)) being a [(finite) field.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)  When $p = 2$, we have $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{2}$ so that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ has only one solution in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used that one often enough or recently enough to recognize it.